# OpenMP parallel outer loop but serial inner loop

Tags: c, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

This might be a trivial question, but I'm encountering some issues with the parallelization of the following section of my code. I hope someone can help clearing up any issues (if there is any). By the way, the code runs perfectly in serial. I will start by presenting the code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(P,Q,WE,CEx,EA,Pn,Wxlim)  private(i,j,ij)
for(j=0;j<m;j++)
{
    P[j] = -EA[j]/(CEx[j]+1.0E-20);
    Q[j] =  Pn[j]/(CEx[j]+1.0E-20);

    for(i=1;i<(int)Wxlim[j];i++)
    {
        ij = (i*m)+j;            

        P[ij] = -EA[ij]/((WE[ij]*P[(ij)-m]) + CEx[ij]+1.0E-20);
        Q[ij] = (Pn[ij]-WE[ij]*Q[(ij)-m])/((WE[ij]*P[(ij)-m]) + CEx[ij]+1.0E-20);
    }
}
```

The code seems to run fine for a little bit, then gets a segmentation fault as some point and I'm not sure why. I only want the `j` loop to be parallel and I want the `i` loop to be run in serial. In other words, for each `j` I want a single thread to calculate the `i` loop. As you can see there is a dependency within the `i` loop, but each `i` loop as a whole is independent for a given `j`.  That is why I want to parallelize the outer loop and run the inner loop on independent threads for a given `j`.

For starters, do I have this setup correctly to do as I intend?  I should note that `m` is much larger than the number of threads.  And again, the code runs fine in serial, so I know it's nothing to do with the variables.

Comment: Your code looks correctly parallelized as you want... Where segv?

Comment: You may try to run your code in a memory checker (like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)) or in a debugger to understand where the segmentation fault occurs

Comment: I don't see any reason right now that that code should cause a segmentation fault.  However, your code is highly cache unfriendly (it's using single values from a cache line and throwing the rest away).  You could probably gain more in performance by making your code more cache friendly than with using multiple threads.

Comment: @ Raxman: Highly cache unfriendly? Could you elaborate...I'm not familiar with this concept (probably why it's "highly" cache unfriendly)

Comment: You may have resolved this by now, but in case not, I don't think the problem is here.  Are there any other parallel loops or regions before this, perhaps one which computes the Wxlim array?

Comment: a note: `ij` is defined private, while `P` and `Q` are shared. Have you checked the possibility if two different parallel threads can produce a same `ij` at some point? That could cause race condition for updating values of `P` and `Q`.